# Programmatically update Webform Submission by sid

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I'm trying create/update Webform Submission programmatically. I already know how the create new submission by following the Drupal 8 [API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-create-a-submission). Now I'm trying to build a update method, I refer to the Webform module source-code and API documents but couldn't find a solution. I guess they remove `webform_get_submission` `webform_submission_update` functions in Drupal 8.3 as-well.

```
$values = [
  'webform_id' => 'attendees_info',
  'in_draft' => FALSE,
  'uid' => $uid,
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'token' => 'at_'.$token,
  'uri' => '/webform/attendees/api',
  'remote_addr' => '',
  'data' => [
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'gallery_url' => 'gallery/'.$token,
  ],
];

$webform = Webform::load($values['webform_id']);
$is_open = WebformSubmissionForm::isOpen($webform);

if ($is_open === TRUE) {
    // Validate submission.
    $errors = WebformSubmissionForm::validateValues($values);

    // Check there are no validation errors.
    if (!empty($errors)) {
       return $errors;
    }
    else {
      // Submit values and get submission ID.
      $webform_submission = WebformSubmissionForm::submitValues($values);
      return $webform_submission->id();
    }
}
```

Above is my Submission creation code, I don't know how to do the update method. Is anyone face this issue before? Hope someone will help me on this, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using *\Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface::getData();* and
*\Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface::setData($data);*

```
// Load submission using sid.
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);

// Get submission data.
$data = $webform_submission->getData();

// Change submission data.
$data['element_key'] = 'custom_element_value';

// Set submission data.
$webform_submission->setData($data);

// Save submission.
$webform_submission->save();
```

Comment: Using this code in custom submit handler, new entry is created in webform_submission_data table, instead of updating existing data with sid.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

[jrockowitz's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/972/jrockowitz) [above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246567/2699) code is the correct and clean approach. Below also works, just wanted to share.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->merge('webform_submission_data');
$query->key([
    'sid' => $sid,
    'name' => 'your_custom_key',
])->fields([
    'value' => 'your_value',
]);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: This works too, as $ws->setData() doesn't do any validation, however it may change in the future. Plus, by skipping $ws->save() change_date doesn't get updated which may cause inconsistency later. It's always a good practice to avoid touching row data.

Answer (score 0):

To only change **one** element, use:

```
 $webform_submission->setElementData('element_key', 'custom_element_value')
```

---

For example:

> ```
> /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
> $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);
> $webform_submission->setElementData('element_key', 'custom_element_value');
> $webform_submission->save();
> ```
>
> Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2911356